# How to make php file downloadable in lighttpd

Tags: configuration, lighttpd

I need to allow users to download a php file from my website.
The web server is lighttpd
I the website itself is written in php, so a normal file with php extension is rendered in browser.

How can I offer just one specific php file for download, so when user clicks on a link a download will start instead of rendering of a file.

I don't want to zip the file as a workaround, I want users to be able to just download that php file.

Does anyone know the correct configuration directive for lighttpd?

Answer (score 0):

Rename it to txt or, have another PHP script that prints the PHP code to the user.

Comment: But that would just display it on the page as plaintext file. I am looking for a way to modify the content-type in header somehow so that it will trigger download in browser

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to do it thought a different PHP from the same directory with something like this :

```
$your_file = file_get_contents('script.php');
header('Content-Type: application/txt');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="script.php"');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($your_file));
echo $your_file;
```

Let me know if it works.